# not able to import raster data through raster2pgsql

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I'm new to postgis and I'm not able to get through raster2pgsql.
The problem is:

I want to import a raster (.tif) file using raster2pgsql. But after running the command:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rastergeo.tif -F -t 512*512 public.demelevation > elev.sql
```

I'm getting the error message:

> ACCESS DENIED

Can anyone please guide me, right from beginning?

I'm using geoserver.

Comment: What command are you using? Show us how you proceed so we can help you.

Comment: raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rastergeo.tif -F -t 512*512 public.demelevation > elev.sql

The above command is written in cmd

Comment: Edit that in your question using the edit button (between share and flag). To format it as code indent it by 4 spaces

Comment: Done with the editing part

Comment: I´m guessing from your other question from two days later that you solved this problem. Could you post the solution as an answer?

Comment: The problem is solved. I didn't write the entire command.
The command also included psql -h <your host> -p <port number> -d <database name> -U <username>

Answer (score 0):

You do not have write access to the folder where you are trying to write elev.sql

Answer (score 0):

Change you command to include a more specific path to save your file. For example if you were to save it in the same place as the original raster you would save it to...

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rastergeo.tif -F -t 512*512 public.demelevation > c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\elev.sql
```

Instead of trying to save into the directory where `raster2pgsql` is being run from, probably in postgres/*verNum*/bin -- where you probably don't have permission.